# Logic challenge in math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

i get stuck in logic problem.

suppose $L=\{P,Q\}$ which $P$ and $Q$ are one-place predicate. if $A$ is a set with three element. how many way we can convert $A$ into a Structure for $L$ that Interpretation $P$ and $Q$ has non-empty intersection?

i see the result is $37$. how this be calculated? any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a combinatorial argument:

Let $A=\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}\}$. Clearly at lease one of $P(a_{1})$, $P(a_{2})$, $P(a_{3})$ has to hold.

Now if $P$ holds true of all three elements, then as long as $Q$ holds true of at least one element the result holds. Now there are 7 different ways (${3 \choose 1} + {3 \choose 2} + {3 \choose 3}$) in ways in which $Q$ can be interpreted so that the intersection you are looking for is non-empty.

Now suppose $P$ holds true of one element. Say $a_{i}$. Now if $Q$ only holds of one element it has to be $a_{i}$ as well in order to meet the conditions. If $Q$ holds true of two elements then there are $2$ possibilities, i.e. $Q$ holds true of $a_i$ and one other element (e.g. if $i=1$, then we have to have either $Q(a_{1})$ and $Q(a_{2})$ in $A$ or $Q(a_{1})$ and $Q(a_{3})$ in $A$). If $Q$ holds true of all three elements, then you have the required property. Since $i$ was arbitrary, we have $3\times(1+2+1)=12$ different interpretations.

Now try and figure out what happens if $P$ holds of two elements? The argument is very similar to what I've written down. Once you count those, add all three up and you will have your answer.

EDIT: The last answer is $37$ and if you finish the counting argument above you'll get this answer. Since you asked for clarification; Suppose that only $P(a_{1})$ holds in $A$. i.e. $A\models{P(a_{1})}\wedge\neg{P(a_{2})}\wedge\neg{P(a_{3})}$, then in order for the intersection to be non-empty, you need either $A\models{Q(a_{1})\wedge\neg{Q(a_{2})}\wedge\neg{Q(a_{3})}}$ or $A\models{Q(a_{1})\wedge{Q(a_{2})}\wedge\neg{Q(a_{3})}}$ or $A\models{Q(a_{1})\wedge{Q(a_{2})}\wedge{Q(a_{3})}}$ or $A\models{Q(a_{1})\wedge\neg{Q(a_{2})}\wedge{Q(a_{3})}}$ (note that no two of these can occur at once). Now if you consider cases where only $P(a_2)$ and where only $P(a_3)$ holds in $A$, when you add all these together you get $4+4+4=12$ different cases. You have to count the number of other possibilities too.

Note that my original answer does the same by counting $3\times{(1+2+1)}=12$.

Edit: The last case can be calculated by $3\times{(2+3+1)}=18$ (note here if $Q$ holds true of any two elements in $A$, then the intersection we are looking for is non-empty hence the three). Adding all three together we have 37.

Comment: the last answer is 37. i try to understand your hint, but i couldn't.

Comment: dear Danul G, can u describe more detail? i couldn't solve for the next condition... i'm a computer scientist.

Comment: @user153695 I have added more details. Try to do it by yourself. Tell me what you tried and where you got stuck if you don't get the answer.

Comment: @user153695 Also you might want to change the question title to something that actually describes the problem.

Comment: i means, because i'm a computer scientist, i read 1 logic book for get familiar with logic. i'm not expert in this field. you are so right and so clarify your answer. but if it's possible, please answer in brief how get 37. you are mathematician :) and so familiar with logic ! you means (25 for hold two + 12 for hold one ) ? yes ?

Comment: @user153695 This is not really logic as a logician would call it but a combinatorial argument. If you really want to familiarize yourself with the subject, you should try and figure the rest out. If not, me just writing the rest of the answer won't really help you understand anything.

Try and do it on your own and see what you get. If you are still stuck after a couple of days, let me know and I'll edit the solution to be complete.

Comment: okey, i try to solve in the next hours todays, if i get stuck i call you tomorrow. i know the rest solution is not help me, but i think you should mentioned some additional tips for the rest :) thanks again from you worth time...

Comment: Dear Danul G, i couldn't solve it for lot's of hour. would you please help me.

Comment: you means add 12+12+18?

Comment: No, 7+12+18. Please re read the answer. All the details are in there now.